# chartMouseListener and MouseListener

Tags: java, mouseevent, jfreechart, mouselistener, mouseclick-event

Why at first works chartMouseClicked (JFreeChart library), and already then mouseClicked?

```
boolean isDoubleClicked = false;
chartPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            if (me.getClickCount() == 2 &&) {
                isDoubleClicked = true;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}
    });



chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
            if (isDoubleClicked)
                System.out.println("Double clicked!");
        }
        @Override
        public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent cme) {}
    });
```

So, `System.out.println("Double clicked!");` not works. How to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different listener objects here, one is a `MouseListener` instance (that listens to mouse events on the panel) and the other is a `ChartMouseListener` instance (that listens to mouse events on the chart in the panel).  They are registered in separate listener lists, and the `isDoubleClicked` field from one object isn't visible to the other object.

The reason that `ChartMouseListener` is separate from `MouseListener` is that [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) creates its own events that contain additional information about the entity in a chart that is "underneath" the mouse pointer.

Comment: I decided add all information in `MouseListener` and remove from `ChartMouseListener`. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

To add up on @DavidGilbert, you can also use `ChartMouseEvent.getTrigger().getClickCount()` to detect double-click in the chart.